# Nginx trying to load image files from server root rather then project root location

Tags: css, laravel, nginx, npm, sass

Quick question, shouldn't be too hard... hopefully.

I'm running Nginx with two Laravel projects being hosted. The following directories are where they are being stored.

`/var/www/site.kara`
`/var/www/site.arkmanager`

The location of the projects are `http://10.0.0.2/kara` and `http://10.0.0.2/arkmanager`.

The `site.kara` laravel project is loading images just fine. However I have an issue with the `site.arkmanager` locating images in my CSS file. It is also having issues loading FontAwesome webfonts files as well, due to the css code looking in the root of the server and not in the project directory. (CSS Code Below) I look at the console and there is an error...

[image: Console Error Log]

So, according to this error its trying to get the image file from the server root directory? It isn't adding the `/arkmanager` portion of the image location... the image location is: `http://10.0.0.2/arkmanager/images/app/hero-background.png`. So I'm thinking that I screwed up my NGINX default file somehow, even though its not giving me any errors when running `sudo nginx -t`. A little bit of insight would be helpful in solving this issue.

My CSS class property, if its relevant to the problem, putting here just in case:

```
#hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("/images/app/hero-background.png") top center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file contents. I am not running SSL due to the fact that this is a local server (second computer) inside my internal network and not available to the public.

```
# HTTP Server Block
server {
    # Port that the web server will listen on.
    listen 80 default_server;

    # Root Folder
    root /var/www/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # IP ADDRESS
    server_name _;

    # Root Location
    location / {
        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Karas Worlds Nested Location
    location /kara {
        alias /var/www/site.kara/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @kara;

        # PHP FPM configuration.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            #Include Fast CGI Snippets
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # Define the PHP Script Filename
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets)
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @kara {
        rewrite /kara/(.*)$ /kara/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # End Karas World Nested Location

    # Ark Manager Nested Location
    location /arkmanager {
        alias /var/www/site.arkmanager/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @arkmanager;

        # PHP FPM configuration.
            location ~ \.php$ {
                #Include Fast CGI Snippets
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # Define the PHP Script Filename
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets)
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    location @arkmanager {
        rewrite /arkmanager/(.*)$ /arkmanager/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # Ark Manager Nested Location


    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #Include Fast CGI Snippets
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets)
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Also side note here is a screenshot of my `npm run dev` command running and compiling successfully, just in case anyone thought that the CSS file might have been borked.

[image: npm run dev command]

This is what what the application looks like on my local dev machine:

https://prnt.sc/vtu6f6

https://prnt.sc/vtu6y0

This is what it looks like on the local ubuntu server running nginx:

https://prnt.sc/vtu6r5

https://prnt.sc/vtu77h

Comment: This is server configuration, not programming. [sf] would be a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this issue is a server only issue and could be an issue with something in my css, or laravel configurations. Not sure if it could be the filesystem, the app_url not being set correctly, or a myriad of other laravel related issues. I have also posted my question there per your suggestion.

Comment: "It isn't adding the `/arkmanager` portion of the image location" you have an absolute path name in your CSS, so it won't add anything to it.

Comment: Changed to: `url("images/app/hero-background.png")` and it gives me an npm error (https://prnt.sc/vtul36) AND a laravel error (https://prnt.sc/vtulwu)

Comment: That's just making it relative to the CSS file. You'd probably need a `..` or two in there?

Comment: The image is stored in /public/images... the sass file is stored in resources/sass/app... so what you're saying is i should be putting `../../../public/images/app/hero-background.png`? If thats the case then I have to go through over 100 files and search and edit all the paths to use the strict file location. There has to be an easier way. The local development environment with `php artisan serve` shows and loads css, js, and image files just fine. Why would it work on my dev machine and not on this local dummy server?

Comment: Also, I did make that change just to see if it worked, and it didn't... its still trying to load the file from the root directory... Dev Panel Computer Property of the #hero section: https://prnt.sc/vtuxqd